# How To create a url link and send it to email using php mailer

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

I created a form where a user types in a code,if the code and email exists in database the code then retrieves the email and a token is generated and updated to the database and has to be sent to that email that is retrieved. I am using php mailer to send an email, can someone help me figure what is wrong with the code below, is the url query correct?

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);
session_start();


include 'includes/connect.php';
include 'includes/additional_function.php';
include('classes/phpmailer/phpmailer.php');



if($_POST["Submit"]=="Submit"){

 $idcode=$_POST['idcode'];
 $_SESSION['idcode'] = $post['idcode'];

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE idcode = :idcode";

 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

 $stmt->bindValue(':idcode', $idcode);



 $stmt->execute();

 $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



 if(!empty($result)){
 $email = $result['email'];
 //echo $email;


 $token = generateToken();
 //echo $token;


 $sql = "UPDATE student SET token = :token WHERE email = :email";
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

 $stmt->execute(array(
 ':token' => $token,
 ':email' => $email
 ));


 $result1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 if(!empty($result)){

 {
// $email and $message are the data that is being
// posted to this page from our html contact form
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;




$mail = new PHPMailer();

// set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();

// As this email.php script lives on the same server as our email server
// we are setting the HOST to localhost
$mail->Host = "localhost"; // specify main and backup server

$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication

// When sending email using PHPMailer, you need to send from a valid email address
// In this case, we setup a test email account with the following credentials:
// email: send_from_PHPMailer@bradm.inmotiontesting.com
// pass: password
$mail->Username = "send_from_PHPMailer@bradm.inmotiontesting.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password

// $email is the user's email address the specified
// on our contact us page. We set this variable at
// the top of this page with:
// $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$mail->From = $email;

// below we want to set the email address we will be sending our email to.
$mail->AddAddress("bradm@inmotiontesting.com", "Brad Markle");

// set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
// set email format to HTML
$mail->IsHTML(true);



$mail->Subject = "You Registration Link!";


$mail->Body = 'http://www.domain.com/register/registration.php?token=$token&stud_id=stud_id';
$mail->AltBody = 'Click to Register';


if(!$mail->Send())
{
 echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
}

} 
}

else{


 echo 'You are not Registered';

}

}

?>
```

Comment: so where's the form that should have been posted with this?

Comment: You've based your code on an obsolete example and are using an old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, variables don't get parsed in single quotes

```
$mail->Body = 'http://www.domain.com/register/registration.php?token=$token&stud_id=stud_id';
```

wrap it in double quotes

```
$mail->Body = "http://www.domain.com/register/registration.php?token=$token&stud_id=stud_id";
```

and will not populate themselves in the email sent.

Which for example:

```
$token = "abcde";

echo $var = 'http://www.domain.com/register/registration.php?token=$token&stud_id=stud_id';

echo "<br>";

echo $var = "http://www.domain.com/register/registration.php?token=$token&stud_id=stud_id";
```

will echo the following:

```
http://www.domain.com/register/registration.php?token=$token&stud_id=stud_id
http://www.domain.com/register/registration.php?token=abcde&stud_id=stud_id
```

As you can see, `$token` doesn't get its intended value populated, but echos as `$token` instead of `abcde`.

**Reference:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

This is assuming your conditional statement and POST arrays are kosher.

Plus this `$post['idcode']` needs to read as `$_POST['idcode']` as per `$idcode=$_POST['idcode'];` and error reporting would have helped you here. That's a superglobal http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php and missed the underscore and putting POST in uppercase letters.

If you're unsure:

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

or post your HTML form in your question.

---

**Footnotes:**

Unsure what you want to use `stud_id` for and how that is supposed to be populated. Only you know that. As per `$token&stud_id=stud_id';`

Now, if your query is failing, then that's a different story and you would need to find out why that is and is beyond the scope of the question.

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php