# URL Link not clickable when a Php variable is passed onto it in phpmailer

Tags: php, html, email

Am trying to pass certain php variable as part of a clickable link  to be send via PhpMailer. To this effect, I referenced a solution here but still cannot get it to work
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151519/how-to-create-a-url-link-and-send-it-to-email-using-php-mailer)

```
$site = 'http://example.com';
$user_id = 100;

$msg="Please Click links below.<br> <br>
<a  href='$site/link1.php?id=$user_id'>Link 1</a><br><br>
<a  href='$site/link2.php'>Link 2</a>";         

$msg_body = "Here is your $msg";
```

**Here is my issue:** When I run the Code, the Email get sent successfully but both **link1 and link 2** are not clickable.

here is the code below

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;



// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$site = 'http://example.com';
$user_id = 100;


$msg="Please Click links below.<br> <br>
<a  href='$site/link1.php?id=$user_id'>Link 1</a><br><br>
<a  href='$site/link2.php'>Link 2</a>";         

$msg_body = "Here is your $msg";



    //PHP Mailer Server settings goes here



    $mail->setFrom('henry@mysite.com', "Henry Good");
      $mail->addAddress($reciever@gmail.com, 'Ann Ball);     // Add a recipient
    $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'My Email Subject';
    $mail->Body = $msg_body;
    $mail->AltBody = $msg_body; // for Plain text for non-HTML mails
   $sent =  $mail->send();
```

Comment: Have you checked the final HTML of the email to see if it's valid - specifically the HTML of the link and the content of the href attribute? Also have you tested this with multiple mail clients?

Comment: The html is valid.
 The problem is that its not clickable. I think its the variable `$site` and `$user_id that` is causing the issue.
If I remove the variable and try something like below `<a  href='http://example.com/link2.php'>This works</a>` it works.

Comment: Well, the code you've shown would produce that exact same output (demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/490e57fd4563ac297a4473d39836e54aa77d1568), so it's unclear how or why that could stop it working... the mail client has no idea whether you hard-coded the link or used PHP to generate it, the HTML which gets sent with the email should be identical in either case. Have you checked the raw source code of the email (most mail clients have a tool for doing this) to check it really, definitely contains exactly what you expected?

Comment: you're missing some quotes in the `addAddress` function

Comment: ADyson wrote reasonable comment above. Please check if your html is valid. 
 
@Nancy Moore, could you please open your result in browser and check if links do work fine there? Is that possible to share the source html output with us?

Comment: Very likely there is an issue with string concatenation and the <a> tag is closing before word 'Link 1'. Probably it's worth  try to use `sprintf('%d', $user_id)` function to have more strict checking and more readable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do something like that:

1. `$mail->Body = html_entity_decode($msg_body);` or
2. `$mail->set('Body', $msg_body);`
3. In any way try to wrap your message body in `<html></html>` to get a valid code. Something like my sample below:

`$mail->Body = sprintf('<html><body>%s<body><html>', $msg_body);`

I hope something from that will help you sort your issue.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have tried all the method you listed above but none is working yet.  

The html is valid.
 The problem is that its not clickable. I think its the variable `$site` and `$user_id that` is causing the issue.
If I remove the variable and try something like below `<a  href='http://example.com/link2.php'>This works</a>` it works. Please is there anyway i can rest those variables in the link

Answer (score -1):

An issue i've found so far is the way you concatenated $site and $user_id variable to the content of $msg variable

```
$site = 'http://example.com';
$user_id = 100;
$msg = "Please Click links below. <br/><br/><a href='" . $site . "/link1.php?id=" . $user_id .
        "'>Link</a><br><br><a href='" . $site . "/link2.php?id=" . $user_id . "'>Link2</a>";
```

For more on string operations https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: There's no issue with the way it's being done currently - demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/490e57fd4563ac297a4473d39836e54aa77d1568 . Your suggestion isn't wrong but equally it won't produce a different result, so there's no reason to change it to this version.

Comment: You might be right though. It might be an issue of phpMailer trying to send the msg as plain text. Having $msg content wrapped in a paragraph tag might do the trick 
"<p>Please Click links below. <br/><br/><a href='" . $site . "/link1.php?id=" . $user_id .
        "'>Link</a><br><br><a href='" . $site . "/link2.php?id=" . $user_id . "'>Link2</a></p>";

Comment: What do you mean?? `$mail->isHTML(true);` controls whether the message is sent as plain text or not. If the message is plain text, then adding extra HTML to the HTML which is already there it won't make the mail client interpret it as HTML suddenly. And adding a `<p>` won't magically make a hyperlink clickable, either. Something else is going on, the OP has failed to produce a [mre] demonstrating the issue so we should just wait for clarification.